# Как получать компоненты через GetComponent из массива? UNITY, C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

как получить getcomponent transform из элемента массива (например, i)?

Comment: Объясните откуда берется массив, это результат работы `GetComponents()` (не `GetComponent()`) или вы создаете массив вручную?

Answer (score 0):

```
Transform[] tempTransform = new Transform[MainArray.length];
for (int i = 0; i < MainArray.length; i++)
{
    tempTransform[i] = MainArray.transform;
}
```

В данном примере создается массив из всех компонентов Transform вашего основного массива MainArray.

То есть MainArray[i].transform и есть получение компонента Transform элемента массива i.